# E open relative to Y $\Longleftrightarrow$ $E=Y\cap G$, $G$ open

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces, set-theory

**Problem**: Suppose $Y \subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and
only if $E = Y \cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

This problem has many solutions, several on MSE. I wonder though, why does the forward direction use the trick it does? Proof from Rudins book:

> **Proof.**  Suppose $E$ is open relative to $Y$.  To each $p \in E$ there is a positive number $r_p$ such that the conditions $d ( p,q ) < r_p$, $q \in Y$ imply that $q \in E$.  Let $V_p$ be the set of all $q \in X$ such that $d ( p,q ) < r_p$, and define $$G = \bigcup_{p \in E} V_p.$$ Then $G$ is an open subset of $X$, by Theorems 2.19 and 2.24.
>
> Since $p \in V_p$ for all $p \in E$, it is clear that $E \subset G \cap Y$.
>
> By our choice of $V_p$, we have $V_p \cap Y \subset E$ for every $p \in E$, so that $G \cap Y \subset E$.  Thus $E = G \cap Y$, and one half of the theorem is proved.

I can't seem to find the mistake in this very simple proof.

**Proof:** $E$ is open in $Y$ and it is a subset of $X$, so $E=Y\cap G$, where $E=G$. Hence we found such a $G$.

Comment: Suppose $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = E = \{0\}$. Then $E$ is open in $Y$, since the entire space is always open. The $G$ you constructed is $G = \{0\}$, which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, solved